# Enlarging text on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I am new to Ubuntu and am visually impaired. I need to enlarge text and icons on the display across the operating system. I know I can change to full screen in LibreOffice writer, but what about other programs? Can anyone help?

Comment: What's your desktop environment?

Comment: I can tell you a workaround, until someone knows how to do it the right way.  Lower your resolution.  *Most* icons are a fixed size, and will just get bigger.  The same happens with the fonts in some software.

Answer (score 0):

### Unity

Open a terminal and install `compizconfig-settings-manager`

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Start the application `ccsm`, open the category *Accessibility* and enable the helper that you need.

Comment: compizconfig settings manager is also available via Software center, isn't it ?

Comment: @Serg Right, but I prefer the terminal way =)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>System Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Appearance</kbd> has a scale bar that allows you to change size of the icons on the launch bar.

<kbd>System Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Display</kbd> has an option to change the screen resolution: *the lower the resolution, the larger the screen will look.*

Programmatically, this can be achieved with:

```
xrandr --output SCREEN --mode ZZZxYYY
```

where SCREEN is the connected  screen name as reported just by running `xrandr`, and ZZZ and YYY are numbers for one of the resolutions that are also reported by `xrandr`. For example, I'd use `xrandr --output LVDS --mode 800x600` to lower my resolution.

If you find a resolution that works, you can use the above command and add it to start-up applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download **Unity Tweak Tool** in your **Software Center**, and it will allow you to change your font size and style for the rest of your software. That is, if you are using Unity.